# Replacing values in a table with a value from another table (complicated)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a table that contains various values in a single cell. I want to replace part of the value in that cell that matches with a value from another table.

Researched extensively online but could not find a lot of information regarding it.

For example - I have the following table

If part of the value in table 1 matches with table 2, I want it to be replaced with the value from table 2 (second column).

For example in table 1 - value "www.portal.com/kav1232" matches with "www.portal.com/kav1232" in table 2 then the value in the cell from table 1 is replaced with "www.new1.com" but rest of the content from the cell remains the same.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: And how should Access know which parts of strings to match? Always the parts that begin with `www`? What do you mean by 'various values in a single cell' - is this a multi-value field? Or just a string of text?

Comment: You'd better change the structure of the tables, place variable parts in a separate column(s) and generate the final text using queries. In this case, you'll be able to replace variable parts by anything you want without losing performance.

Comment: When I say various values in a single cell - I mean it contains a lot of text, and I want to be able to find one specific word and replace it with another value when that word matches with another table (vlookup).